# Thermodynamic Identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation

I want to show the following thermodynamic identity (Pathria, 3rd Edition, Appendix H, Pg 677):
$$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_w$$

I start with

$$
    dx = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z dy + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y dz  $$
$$ dx = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w dy + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)_y dw
$$

Yielding
$$\left[\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w -  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z  \right] dy =  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y dz -  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)_y dw  
$$
Now consider
$$dz=  \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_w dy +  \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right)_y dw$$
and substitute it in:
$$\left[\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w -  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z  \right] dy =  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y \left[\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_w dy +  \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right)_y dw \right] -  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)_y dw  
$$
Giving:
$$\left[\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w -  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z  - \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_w \right] dy =   \left[\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right)_y  -  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)_y\right] dw  
$$

This is strange though. If the first identity is true, this implies that
$$ \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right)_y  =  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\right)_y$$
Something which can easily be shown to not be true, for $x=yz^2$ where $w=yz,$ so $x=w^2 /y,$ and $z=w/y$.

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Try to have a look at this notes. You should find something useful
https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/TD/partial_derivatives.html

Comment: LOL. I'm answering your question. Give me a while. Are you 100% sure? I'm using chrome on android and everything works fine

Comment: I'm on android, and the link works with chrome and firefox. try to explicitly add https:// in front of the link

Comment: @basics It seems like a Safari specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left you a reference about partial derivatives and some useful notation often used in thermodynamics in the comment.

Anyway, for this identity it's enough to

- write $x(y, z)$ and $z(y, w)$,
- define the composite function $\tilde{x}(y, w) = x(y, z(y, w))$
- evaluate the partial derivative of $\tilde{x}(y, w)$

$\left(\dfrac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial y}\right)_w (y,w) = \left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w (y, z(y, w)) =\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z (y, z(y, w)) +\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y (y, z(y, w))\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_w (y, z(y, w)) $

Comment: I understand this method, but it still leaves the curious question in the OP: "what went wrong?"

Comment: you missed the term $(\partial x /\partial z)_w$ in front of the first term in the square bracket on the rhs. With this missing term, the content of the square brackets reads $(\partial x /\partial w)_y - (\partial x /\partial w)_y \equiv 0$

Comment: Ah yes, I've been starting at a screen all day evidently, thank you!

Comment: do we solve the mystery?

Comment: Yes we definitely do.